# EXTJS 7 areaChart Dynamic markers or marker customizations

Tags: extjs, charts, colors, markers

I am working on area charts whit EXTJS 7.3.1 I want to be able to customize the markers color based on the data value.

How can i do that.

Currently, the markers are set for entire chart. like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulDKq.png)

I would like change the color on the markers when value is < 75

Please let me know

Comment: Please provide fiddle sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom renderer function for the series, [see here in the documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.chart.series.Series.html#cfg-renderer).

Something like this:

```
series: [{
   // your series definition, including marker etc.
   ,renderer: function(sprite, config, rendererData, index) {
      // renderer function must return the changes
      var changes = {};
      // get current record in the chart's store
      var record = rendererData.store.getData().items[index];
      
      // check value only when it is a marker
      if (config.type === 'marker') {
         // replace 'fieldName' with your fieldname
         // and color1 color2 with the desired colors
         changes.fillStyle = record.data.fieldName < 75 ? 
              'color1' : 'color2';
      }
      return changes;
   }
}],
```

Comment: Work juste fine. Thanks a lot!